# Define read only view

Tags: list, permissions

I'm using SharePoint 2007.
I have created Custom list.
On that list I need to create read-only view.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as read only view. You can remove rights to edit items from users so they will not be able to open items for edit and SharePoint will remove all interface for editing items. And you cannot disallow users to change current view. And remember of Access view.

Anyway if you still want to do it I can suggest to use DataViewWebPart and manually delete any editing capabilities. And you don't have to create it from scratch - you can convert traditional ListViewWebPart connected to your desired list into the DahaViewWebPart in a few clicks.

Comment: Then why is there a ReadOnlyView property on the SPView object?

Comment: to Mr K: I couldn't find how to set this property. According to SPView class code this property is mapped to "ReadOnly" attribute of the <View> tag in CAML. I've tried to set it but didn't see any effect. But according to this property usage in SP code it must disable view selection dropdown on the page for example. So it looks this property really must help to define some "read only" view. But anyway it doesn't prevent user from editing list content if he has proper permissions so I can't imagine the right use for such a property.